# Empty pixels in rendered window using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, fxml

I'm writing a window using JavaFX.
If I preview it with JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0, it seems works fine.

When I load it with my application, I use this code:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Client/FXMLForms/MainForm.fxml"));
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.setTitle("Il Covo");
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
     public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
         MainClient.close();
         System.exit(0);
     }
});
stage.show();
```

And it appears, but I got this problem:

[*JavaFX Bug Picture*](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25176009/JavaFX_Bug.PNG)

[image: bug pic]

Pratically, it leaves me 10px bottom and righ side of the window.
Now, I found a "fix", by adding this before the "stage.show()":

```
stage.setWidth(1280.0);
stage.setHeight(720.0);
```

But I would like to understand why it gives me this problem.

*FXML File of the window*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="1280.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <TabPane layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="695.0" prefWidth="1280.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Homepage">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="1280.0">
                     <children>
                        <TreeView prefHeight="666.0" prefWidth="285.0" />
                        <Pane layoutX="285.0" prefHeight="667.0" prefWidth="996.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Orders">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab closable="false" text="Reviews">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab closable="false" text="Cart">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered that issue before. I think it is a bug of JavaFX. The order of code lines become interestingly important to solve this issue. The following is the code that I use in one of my projects and do not encounter that problem:

```
panel = new MyPanel(); //a BorderPane, its size is set using "setPrefSize" method

root = new Group();
root.getChildren().add(panel);

scene = new Scene(root);

stage.setResizable(false);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
stage.sizeToScene();
stage.centerOnScreen();
```

Comment: The line of "stage.sizeToScene();" did the perfect job. Would be nice to find why the JavaFX give this bug. This may be more dynamic, my solution was force the Width - Height of the window, not so nice. Thank you so much for your solution, I will not give you the confirm for the answer to see if someone else know something more.

Comment: Okay, but I found that solution after a long search on the Internet few months ago. So, I don't think there is more than that.